# commit a file that was un-committed

Tags: git

I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere but for some reason I cannot get a straight answer.  I have 2 commits in GIT that I "uncommitted" using

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

Everything worked great except now I want to use those two commits.

They are still showing up in my list of commits. What command do I use to re-commit them?

Is there a command I can use that will commit them by ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git cherry-pick <MD5 hash of commit>` to get back the commit you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use cherry-pick to add the desired commit. you can use a range to select commit range as well and not only a single commit.

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit(s) at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

[image]

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)